# @Media Print Class in Datatable

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

Why my `class` to add `text-align`did not work on `@media print`?

I made an  [**EXAMPLE PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NtRCVO0ctKnLwjCEUAVS?p=preview)

I want that `Right Element` stay on right when user clicks on `Print` button

**Style**

```
@media print {
  td.text-right-print {
    text-align: right!important
  }
}
```

**Tabela**

```
  <table class="table" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Left Thead</th>
        <th>Right Thead</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Left Element</td>
        <td align="right" class="text-right-print">Right Element</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `customize` method of jquery datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
         {
                extend: 'print',
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body).find('table tr td:nth-child(2)')
                        .addClass('rightAlign');
                }
            }
        ]
      });
    });
```

[EXAMPLE PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/mBQQ72hDF8sQwiGEPzUi?p=preview)

Please find the link below for more information:

[DataTable Print Customization](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html)

Comment: Very good, but there is another way? I have a looot of tables and i have only one `.js` to build all datatables

Comment: Is there a `$(win.document.body).find(' table tr td .text-right-print ')` ?

Comment: @Johnson It seems data table is removing all the custom styles on click of print so you will not be able to find using `text-right-print`

Comment: it is strange because if you put in css the html elements like `@media print { 
 td { text-align: right } }` , it works. but with classes no... =(

Comment: I guess it is removing the custom classes not the styles.

Comment: Thats ok... i will try doing this way... Thanks